# Superscripting a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, superscript

Hello I am trying to superscript a string for a plot.

```
hallo= str(round(popt[1],1))
plt.plot(xFit, func(xFit,*popt),color='r', linestyle='--',label=f'Ideales DOE 125 \u03bcJ <= 0,3 \u03bcm F(x) = {round(popt[0],1)} * e$^{hallo}*x$ ')
```

And the result i get is:

[image]

The "-0,2*x" should be superscripted. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It IS making the `-` a superscript.  To get the whole expression in there, you need to enclose the whole expression in curly braces.  Since you have this in an f-string, where curly braces have meaning, that means you need these rather awkward triple-braces

```
plt.plot(xFit, func(xFit,*popt),color='r', linestyle='--',label=f'Ideales DOE 125 \u03bcJ <= 0,3 \u03bcm F(x) = {round(popt[0],1)} * e$^{{{hallo}}}*x$ ')
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to wrap the whole expression with the $$, can't start with e$^10$, rather $e^10$

```
hallo = str(round(popt[1],1))
label = (f'Ideales DOE 125 \u03bcJ <= 0,3 \u03bcm '
         f'F(x) = {round(popt[0],1)} * $e^{hallo}*x$ ')
plt.plot(xFit, func(xFit,*popt),color='r', linestyle='--',label=label)
```

Comment: Whether the `e` is included in the math expression or not is irrelevant.